# Click Through Var Images in a Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently learning basic JavaScript/JQuery but I'm in need of a quick fix to a problem which is slightly beyond what I'm capable of solving right now.

I'm looking to create a feature that allows me to click through images, and when I click on the last image it will return to the first image, in a loop.

(I'm trying to make something similar to this: https://www.antennebooks.com/product/east-end-of-europe/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

this is what I have so far:

```
<script>
var images = [
  "images/img1.png",
  "images/img2.png",
  "images/img3.png",
  "images/img4.png"
]

var step = 0;
changeImage(); 

function changeImage() {

  document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange').src = images[step];
  step++;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code/what you've tried and be more specific about your issue. What is going wrong? What happens? What did you expect to happen? Are you getting any error messages? What have you tried already? etc.

Comment: `step` will produce `0,1,2,3` etc without path nor png . So you change your source without saying so. This will be difficult. If you really want help then u should communicate changes thru this comment area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the function `changeImage()` is called when you click on the image displayed, you just have to change the `step++;` to `step = (step + 1) % images.length;` and place it as the first line of your function.
Each time `step + 1` equals to images.length, step would be reset to 0.

Comment: Not following your logic. `step++ % images.length` is the same correct?

Comment: sorry but, I quite don't understand your question about ````step++ % images.length```` being the same with what?

Comment: Your logic changed the syntax of the formula without explanation, was all. `%` being modulous etc, as in remainder. But then u get rid of the `++` for some reason.

Comment: ok! for example you have 4 images in the ````images```` array. each time you click on the image, step increments. and each time step reach 3, ````(step + 1) % images.length```` would give 0.  
For any ````(step + 1)```` equal to 1, 2 and 3 ````(step + 1) % 4```` would always give 1, 2 and 3. and when ````(step + 1)```` equals to 4, ````(step + 1) % 4```` will give 0

Comment: I understand your logic whereas I just consider the change from OP's code to be possibly a confusion. Not the `%` part which is needed. But on the elimination of `++`. I was just wondering. Anyway upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

We could use jQuery and manipulate the DOM via events, which would make more sense in this situation. A "click" event could be triggered when the user clicks on an image. You could store the images in a set, and when the number of clicks is greater than the length of the set, display the first card and start the process over again. Here is an example of the JavaScript code utilizing the jQuery libary:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var card = $('.card'); //store each card with an image in it in a set
    card.css('cursor', 'pointer'); //set the cursor to pointer to make a click obvious to user
    card.not(':first').hide(); //hide all but the first image (card)
    count = 1; //set the initial click count to one

    card.on('click', function() { //listen for an image to be clicked
        $(this).hide(); //hide the image that has been clicked
        $(this).next().show(); //show the next image
        count++; //increment the count
        if(count > card.length) { //if the count is greater than the length of the set, you are out of images (cards)
            count = 1; //reset the count
            card.first().show(); //show the first card and start process over
        }
    });
});
```

This is the html code that I am using to simulate the events you are looking for:

```
<div class="card" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/path">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>This is a random card and stuff</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/path">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>This is a random card and stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/path">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>This is a random card and stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, we have three cards that basically store our images. If you just want images and no cards, then do that, because that part of it is trivial. What matters here is the programming logic. I would simply set a counter and once that counter is greater than the length of the set (collection) of cards (a set/collection is an array-link object) then show the first card again and start the process over as I showed you in JavaScript.